# TryFind method in Guava throw NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, guava

I get a NullPointerException while running my webapplication, I save a logs and start server again and this error no longer there appeared, but i want protect method to NullPointer never appeared. I sure this line is responsible for this error

```
Vehicle pVehicle =
        Iterables.tryFind(aFactory.getVehicle(), new Predicate<Vehicle>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(Vehicle vehicle) {
                return vehicle.getVehicleBrand().equals(aVehicle.getVehicleBrand());
            }
        }).orNull();
```

But this is not my code, and i don't known, which part may cause this error>
Please, which element can be appeared for this NullPointer and how protect this code

Comment: Please add the stacktrace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Stacktrace only point to  metod and line wiih code above

Comment: @MonikaGalińska Second line or fifth?

Comment: Exactly to the first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following statements:

- `aFactory` - Because of the `getVehicle()` call.
- `aFactory.getVehicle()` - Because Iterables.tryFind expects a non-null Iterable
- `vehicle` - Because of the `getVehicleBrand()` call
- `aVehicle` - Because of the `getVehicleBrand()` call
- `vehicle.getVehicleBrand()` - Because of the `.equals()` call

If any of these were null it would cause an `NullPointerException`

Comment: It had to be getVehicleBrand() , and i protected this element

Answer (score 1):

can generate null pointer :

```
aFactory.getVehicle() : if aFactory is null
vehicle.getVehicleBrand() : if vehicle is null
aVehicle.getVehicleBrand() : if aVehicle is null
```